# How to modify field_suffix after form submit?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a form with a custom suffix (#field_suffix) for a field. I need to change the suffix value after the form has been submitted. Which hook should I use to achieve this ?

**Sample Code :**

```
$form['field_test']['#field_suffix']='Suffix-1';
```

**Edit:**
I want to show "Suffix-1" when editing form and "Suffix-2" during display of content.

Comment: Is the form using ajax?

Comment: No I'm not using ajax. I just want to show "Suffix-1" when editing form and "Suffix-2" during display of content.

Comment: "suffix 2 when display content" ??? Where is the form displayed? What is the form for? I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: When I'm editing a content type (node/edit), my "field_test" should show "Suffix 1" as the #field_suffix. After I save the content type and view it, it should show "Suffix 2" for "field_test"

Comment: so both suffix1 and suffix2 are displayed on the edit form? But suffix1 if it is new content but suffix 2 if editing content that has been saved before?

Comment: No. Only "suffix 1" is displayed during node edit. After saving node, the "suffix 1" should be changed to "Suffix 2".

Comment: ? the form is only displayed when editing the form if this is a node edit form. How do you expect to display the suffix if you are not viewing the edit form I'm confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to achieve this functionality.

```
function hook_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
$node->content['field_test'][0]['#markup'] = $node->content['field_test']['#items'][0]['value'].'Suffix-2';
}
```

Comment: Although this code achieves what I require, I'm not sure if this is the right approach. So I'm not marking this answer as accepted until I know for sure that there is no alternate method.